# DC.JS Selecting a Bar on Click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to call a function on a bar chart when the user clicks on a specific bar. I realized I need to use a renderlet to add a listener to the render function and then from there create a grouping of each bar that will have an on click event added to it.

Assuming with any generic bar chart I am calling this:

```
barChart.on('renderlet', function(chart, filter)
{
    // TODO Select the bars here and add an on click function
});
```

Only problem is that I am unable to find out how to do a d3.select call on a bar using that chart object. I don't see anything like bars in the object when I dump it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of thing, the easiest way to find out is just to go to the source.  In this case,

```
    var enter = bars.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/bar-chart.js#L90-L92

So the selector is `rect.bar`. Also, the convenience method `chart.selectAll()` is better than using d3 directly, because it will only select within the current chart.

Finally, to avoid stomping on the events used by dc.js internally, you may want to namespace your event handler.

Adding it up,

```
barChart.on('renderlet.barclicker', function(chart, filter)
{
    chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click.custom', function(d) {
        // use the data in d to take the right action
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked flawlessly, my knowledge of Javascript is from 10+ years ago so I was unable to figure out how to get that from their code.

Comment: It is definitely non-obvious. I thought I was answering just the selector question, and then I was like, "and this, and that"... Hopefully this can become the new canonical answer.